# Index update process are running repeatedly in same index

Tags: sitecore-api

We have this api that is creating and publishing item programmatically. (This item is created under a bucket folder). I've checked the logs and noticed that in between the process, our index are being update repeatedly. Why?

```
7164 12:05:27 INFO  Item Import Process for Id 947302701 - Started
7164 12:05:27 INFO  Getting source items for Availability field - Started
7164 12:05:27 INFO  Getting source items for Availability field - Completed
7164 12:05:27 INFO  Getting existing item for Id: 947302701 - Started
7164 12:05:27 INFO  Getting existing item for Id: 947302701 - Completed
7164 12:05:27 INFO  Creating new item for language en and Id 947302701 - Started
ManagedPoolThread #6 12:05:27 INFO  Job started: Index_Update_IndexName=sitecore_master_index
ManagedPoolThread #6 12:05:27 INFO  Job ended: Index_Update_IndexName=sitecore_master_index (units processed: )
ManagedPoolThread #7 12:05:27 INFO  Job started: Index_Update_IndexName=sitecore_master_index
ManagedPoolThread #5 12:05:27 INFO  Job started: Index_Update_IndexName=sitecore_marketing_asset_index_master
ManagedPoolThread #12 12:05:27 INFO  Job started: Index_Update_IndexName=sitecore_testing_index
ManagedPoolThread #2 12:05:27 INFO  Job started: Index_Update_IndexName=sitecore_fxm_master_index
ManagedPoolThread #9 12:05:27 INFO  Job started: Index_Update_IndexName=sitecore_list_index
ManagedPoolThread #18 12:05:27 INFO  Job started: Index_Update_IndexName=social_messages_master
ManagedPoolThread #12 12:05:27 INFO  Job ended: Index_Update_IndexName=sitecore_testing_index (units processed: )
ManagedPoolThread #7 12:05:27 INFO  Job ended: Index_Update_IndexName=sitecore_master_index (units processed: )
ManagedPoolThread #2 12:05:27 INFO  Job ended: Index_Update_IndexName=sitecore_fxm_master_index (units processed: )
ManagedPoolThread #9 12:05:28 INFO  Job ended: Index_Update_IndexName=sitecore_list_index (units processed: )
ManagedPoolThread #18 12:05:28 INFO  Job ended: Index_Update_IndexName=social_messages_master (units processed: )
ManagedPoolThread #5 12:05:28 INFO  Job ended: Index_Update_IndexName=sitecore_marketing_asset_index_master (units processed: )
ManagedPoolThread #15 12:05:28 INFO  Job started: Index_Update_IndexName=sitecore_master_index
ManagedPoolThread #15 12:05:28 INFO  Job ended: Index_Update_IndexName=sitecore_master_index (units processed: )
ManagedPoolThread #8 12:05:28 INFO  Job started: Index_Update_IndexName=sitecore_master_index
7164 12:05:28 INFO  Editing item for language en and Id 947302701 - Started
7164 12:05:28 INFO  Manage Tag field  - Started
7164 12:05:28 INFO  Manage Tag field  - Completed
7164 12:05:28 INFO  Manage Availability field  - Started
7164 12:05:28 INFO  Manage Availability field  - Completed
7164 12:05:28 INFO  Publishing item for language en and Id 947302701 - Started
ManagedPoolThread #10 12:05:28 INFO  Job ended: Index_Update_IndexName=sitecore_master_index (units processed: )
ManagedPoolThread #10 12:05:28 INFO  Job started: Index_Update_IndexName=sitecore_master_index
ManagedPoolThread #10 12:05:28 INFO  Job ended: Index_Update_IndexName=sitecore_master_index (units processed: )
ManagedPoolThread #10 12:05:28 INFO  Job started: Index_Update_IndexName=sitecore_master_index
ManagedPoolThread #10 12:05:29 INFO  Job ended: Index_Update_IndexName=sitecore_master_index (units processed: )
7164 12:05:29 INFO  Publishing item for language en and Id 947302701 - Completed
7164 12:05:29 INFO  News Import Process for Id 947302701 - Completed
```

The start of said api process begins to the first line:

`Item Import Process for Id 947302701 - Started`

And when I created the item for english translation, the index update kicks in:

`Creating new item for language en and Id 947302701 - Started`

But as you can see index are being repeated. I'll take sitecore_master_index as an example. It started on `ManagedPoolThread #6`, though it ended as expected it started again at `ManagedPoolThread #7` and so on...

What is the possible problem?

We are using Sitecore 8.2

Comment: I doubt there is any issue. Sitecore often initiates more than one save when creating an item, which triggers the index to update. If you are doing a lot of these updates all at once, you can use the [`BulkImportContext` and `EventDisabler`](https://horizontalintegration.blog/2016/02/12/disablers-disablers-disablers-disablers-a-lesson-in-mass-sitecore-updates/) to limit the events and history items created during that process.

Comment: I'm with Dan on this. I don't see any indication of a problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Answering this question to share my knowledge as I stumbled upon similar logs recently in one of my environments. The continuous index update jobs running one after the other is due to the **syncMaster** indexing strategy applied on indexes by default. Like Dan said in comment, it doesnt indicate a problem but if you are programatically creating/publishing items, you should use the BulkImportContext and EventDisabler beside SecurityDisabler in your code to prevent triggering these jobs.

---

SyncMaster indexing provides almost real-time indexing and updates indexes based on various events in Sitecore like save etc. This is an expensive strategy and can impact performance.

Comment: Obligatory warning about the use of EventDisabler: it can lead to unexpected issues, so use sparingly.